# How to manage multiple components with IBM Bluemix Track & Plan

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

We have an application that is comprised of multiple distinct components (different functions / languages).

Is it possible in IBM Bluemix to use a single Track & Plan feature to manage the work items for the components but keep the source code in separate git repositories?  For example, I would like to have one backlog for the overall application which is then backed by 5 separate git repos which house the individual components (project-frontend, project-backend, project-queue etc..).

If this is not possible does anybody have a pattern that has worked in streamlining the overall Track & Plan and still enabling the delivery pipeline / managing individual git repos?  Ideally I'd like to centralize task management but keep the code distributed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, there is not a way to manage distributed git repos from a single *Track & Plan* project in an integrated fashion.  That is not to say that it cannot be done manually, but you would need to link to commits in the remote repos in a given work item.

This can be done through the **Links** tab of any given work item and using the **Add SVN Revisions** or **Add Related Artifacts**.  This would allow you to link to the remote repos (whether in IDS, GitHub, or private SCM tooling), while still leveraging *Track & Plan* as an overall planning repo.

Some of this is due to the way projects are constructed in *IBM Bluemix DevOps Services* today.  A single project has the notion of a single git repo, a single Track & Plan instance, and a single Build Pipeline.  Some of these requirements are expanding, but the platform provides integration capabilities to work with your code the way you need to right now.  For example, project owners can build from remote GitHub repos in the project's Build Pipeline, so that code can be managed as you see fit, but built and deployed on *IBM Bluemix*.

Comment: Rick, I wanted to follow-up and confirm that I have gone with the approach above (manually using Related Artifacts).  A little cumbersome but does the trick.  Hopefully allowing multiple native repos per Track & Plan or some type of aggregate Track & Plan will be in DevOps Services near future.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up!  I'll get this issue on the radar of the DevOps Services team so there is more visibility.  If you have any issues, suggestions or details on how you'd like to see it work differently, follow-up here and I'll make sure they see it.

Comment: I wanted to come back to this now that the team has several months experience with the aforementioned process.  Things are working great!  The extra step for commit linking is not ideal but also not a deal breaker vs the other features we benefit from.  Currently we have one main Track & Plan projects that oversees the work items for 10 different components.