# Managing mutiple projects with Bluemix DevOps Track and Plan

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

We have several closely related DevOps projects each with their own jazz git repositories in our Bluemix DevOps account. Each project has its own stories/tasks/defects etc.

What is the current best method to gain a single view of the cumulative backlogs of all projects so we can have one place to prioritize items and plan sprints across all projects. If DevOps Track and Plan can not do this. Is there a 3rd party tool that can integrate with DevOps/Bluemix that will do this for us?

Answer (score 3):

Not a perfect solution, but I asked a very similar question and have had success using the approach described for several projects:

[How to manage multiple components with IBM Bluemix Track & Plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020485/how-to-manage-multiple-components-with-ibm-bluemix-track-plan)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a supported capability at the moment.

I've passed your question on to DevOps Services' developers. We're adding features to Bluemix and Bluemix DevOps Services all the time.